# Given f(x) and its FFT F(u), I need to prove that df/dx = F(u)*2iu(pi)/n

Tags: image-processing, fft, convolution

Given $f(x)$ and its FFT $F(u)$, I need to prove that $df/dx = F(u) * 2iu\pi /n.$

$df/dx = f'(x)$ and $n$ is the number of pixels of the one dimensional image $f$.

I tried to use the convolution theorem using conv($f[1 -1]$) which is the same as $df/dx$ and in the frequency domain it's $F(u) * FFT([1 -1])$ however there sizes don't match.

Comment: @JasonR please help with the full solution. we i tried it as well.and had some problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should have been a comment on the question but is too long to fit within
the 500-character limit.

The $f$ that is the subject of this question is a *sequence* or vector of $n$ numbers
$$[f_0, f_1, \ldots, f_{n-1}] ~~ \text{or} ~~ \left[f[0], f[1], \ldots, f[n-1]\right] 
~~ \text{or} ~~ \left[f(0), f(1), \ldots, f(n-1)\right]$$
depending on choice of notation, and its Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) $F$ (called the
FFT by the OP) is another *sequence* or vector of $n$ numbers. Thus,
it is not clear what the derivative $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x) = f^\prime(x)$ means
since the *argument* of $f(\cdot)$ is an integer and not a continuous variable.  One
could attempt to make sense of what is intended by looking at the OP's approach to the
problem via (cyclic or periodic) convolution with the sequence $[1, -1]$ (actually should have been $[1,-1,0,0,\ldots, 0]$ which results in replacing $f_i$ by $f_{i+1}-f_i$.
Now, we are getting closer to the notion of differentiation since the derivative of
a continuous function is obtained by looking at the limit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ as 
$h \to 0$. Here we have the closest we can get since we are
using $\frac{f(i+1)-f(i)}{1} = f_{i+1}-f_i$, and of course $1$ cannot "approach" $0$.
Unfortunately, this does not give the desired result.  The $k$-th term of the
DFT of $[1,-1,0,0,\ldots, 0]$
is readily computed from the *definition* (no FFTs needed)
as $1 - e^{-j2\pi k/n}$, and so the DFT of the "derivative" sequence
$f_{i+1}-f_i$ has $k$-th term $F_k(1 - e^{-j2\pi k/n})$ which is *not*
what the OP wants to prove.

So, what *does* the OP want to prove? It is 
$\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx} \mathbf{=} F(u)*j(2\pi u/n)$.
This needs clarification on two grounds. First, the left side
of this equality is a function of $x$, the right side a function
of $u$. So what does it mean to say the two are **equal?** 
Second, what the right side means needs clarification. Does
the $*$ mean *multiplication* of the two complex numbers $F(u)$ and
$j(2\pi u/n)$, or is the $*$ denoting *complex conjugation* of $F(u)$
before the multiplication, or does $*$ denote *convolution* so
that $F(u)*j(2\pi u/n)$ means the $u$-th term of the (cyclic or periodic)
convolution of the *sequences* $[F_0,F_1,\ldots,F_{n-1}]$ and 
$[1, j(2\pi/n),j(2\pi 2/n), \ldots, j(2\pi (n-1)/n)]$?
The closest match occurs if we assume that $=$ is a typographical
error and that what is meant is not the *equality* that the OP
claims is needed. Instead, suppose that what was really asked
for but mistranslated by the OP is that **the $k$-th term of
the DFT of $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}$**
by which is meant the *sequence* with $i$-th term $f_{i+1}-f_i$ 
is $F_ke^{j2\pi k/n}$ (another typo, the missing exponential!). As
noted above, this is not quite right: it should be
$F_k(1 - e^{-j2\pi k/n})$. Note, incidentally, that the inverse
DFT of the sequence with $k$-th term $F_ke^{j2\pi k/n}$ is a
*cyclic shift* of the sequence $f$; see, for example, 
[this
Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Shift_theorem)

But maybe as a non-expert in image processing I am missing something completely
and so I await clarification from the OP, or perhaps a more detailed
explanation from @JasonR of the method outlined in his comment on the OP's
question.

Comment: I should have thought more when I read the OP. I was thinking of the continuous-time Fourier transform instead, which has the well-known property that differentiation in the time-domain yields scaling in the frequency domain by a factor proportional to $\omega$. I'm going to remove my misleading comment.

Comment: I suspect what he means is that if P is some sort of "derivative like" operator in the discrete domain, then $FFT\{Pf\} = G[u] = F[u] 2 i \pi u/n$ where $F[u] = FFT\{f\}$ and $n$ is the number of samples?

Comment: @thang Yes, he might mean that, but he says something completely different. Perhaps the OP will return some time and clarify his meaning.

Comment: Yeah you're right... the post itself makes no sense to me as is.   That's the only way in which I can make sense of it.